# Is it possible to get back a response from the percolator when inserting a document?

Tags: elasticsearch

While searching for a solution that allows me to trigger some actions whenever data is inserted I've found the percolator API from elasticsearch. I have read quite a few pages until I recognized that all queries using the percolator API are using GET.

Is it the case that for a use case of inserting documents and wanting to know which ones matched a query I would need to do two requests? From the pages I get the impression I would have to insert the document first and then ask the percolator index with the same document if it had matched. Or is there a query parameter or similar to let elasticsearch include the percolator response into the response I get from the insert?

Comment: If you mean percolate while indexing, it's possible with 0.90 but removed with the new percolator in master (1.0). The reason for the removal is that it is the bigger piece that prevented the percolator from being distributed in 0.90, as you need both the queries and the documents in the same node in order for it to be performant. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I meant percolate while indexing. It would have been nice if it would work. I don't know enough about the internals of elasticsearch to see how indices are treated and why it is good that the percolator resides somewhere else as the documents. I'm just starting to use elasticsearch and I'm building a log concentrator with notification support. Meaning based on matched incoming events/logs I can initiate callbacks to trigger some stuff. I have the feeling that doing 2 requests on every event could be too much and I need a different soluton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your question I believe you are looking at elasticsearch 1.0, at the moment available in Beta2. This detail is important as the percolator has been rewritten in 1.0 and looks quite different compared to the one available in 0.90.

You normally use the percolator to register queries, which get stored. Then you can percolate a document to know how many queries it matches, without actually indexing it.

What many people need is the additional step of indexing the document as well, thus it's nice to be able to do both percolate and indexing in the same request, so that you can both index the document and get back the queries that it matches. This used to be possible in 0.90 using the so called percolate while indexing. It is the only feature that was removed with the rewrite to 1.0, to be able to better distribute the registered queries and scale them out as well.

In fact, with 0.90 the queries are stored in a reserved index, called `_percolator`, which always has 1 shard and `auto_expand_replica` set to `true`. That means that every node will contain all the queries, as that single shard will be automatically replicated to all nodes. The main reason behind this is that when you want to index a document and percolate at the same time, in order to do it in a perfomant way you need to make sure that the two shards that  you need to hit (queries and data) are on the same node. If all queries are on all nodes, this is guaranteed thus percolate while indexing is possible and will be fast enough. But there's a big limitation, which is why the percolator has been rewritten: there's a limit to the number of queries you can register, as they'll go in a single shard.

With 1.0, you can register queries against any index, and they'll be registered under a reserved type called `.percolator`. You can then scale out with queries as well, as they are in a normal index and you can define the number of shards. The disadvantage is that you don't have a whole copy of the queries on each node, thus percolating while indexing is not possible. What you can do though, which is equivalent but consists of two requests is:

1. index the document
2. [percolate the existing document](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-percolate.html#_percolating_an_existing_document) by id, without needing to send the whole document again

Step 2 can be done right after the index operation returns, as it executes internally a get by id, which works in real-time, thus no need to wait nor refresh the index.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The percolate by index seems then to be the best idea. That doubles the number of requests to the database. But that will do for the time being giving my time to come up with a better approach.

Comment: Ok, so now ES is at 1.3.2 -- what's the verdict? If this now a supported feature? Just a bit confused. It seems to say: "This will never be possible but you can just percolate the document id" vs. "Yeah, the feature is coming" -- looking for clarity just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this wouldn't be possible.

From [the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/percolator/)..

> The _percolator which holds the repository of registered queries is just a another index in ES.

Since the `percolator` is another index, one would need to hit ES with another query directed at `_percolator` as the index.

Comment: I cannot see why this shouldn't be possible. The percolator index is associated to the index while being addressed as /my-index/.percolator. So I cannot see why elasticsearch shouldn't be capable to use the percolator index on storage time in the index the percolator is associated with.

Comment: Well - I guess that's by design. Ref [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html). What you say about being able to have multi-index query, holds true for all indices except the `Explain` and `Percolate` APIs.

Comment: You are both right, as I think you are talking about two different versions of elasticsearch. 0.90, current stable version, has a specific index (_percolator) for the queries. 1.0, available in beta2,  can register queries under any index, and it uses the .percolator type to do that.